# PHP First day of month using DateTime

Tags: php

I have a datetime in php:

```
$datetime=new DateTime();
```

How can I get day of week:

```
$datetime->format("w");
```

But for first day of current `$datetime` month?

Comment: just use this single line code `echo date("l",strtotime('first day of this month'));`  `///sunday`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the `->modify()` method to adjust accordingly:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->modify('first day of this month');
$output = $datetime->format("w");
echo $output; // 0 - sunday
```

Without the relative date time string:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setDate($dt->format('Y'), $dt->format('m'), 1);
$output = $dt->format('w');
echo $output;
```

Comment: @PaulCrovella yeah i forgot they share the same parsing with `strtotime`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

> Requires PHP 5.3 to work ("first day of" is introduced in PHP 5.3).
>
> Otherwise the example above is the only way to do it:

l = A full textual representation of the day of the week

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->modify('first day of this month');
echo $output = $datetime->format("l"); //Sunday
```

Alternative:

```
echo date("l", strtotime(date('Y-m-01'))); //Sunday
```